# Clock override gnome extension stopped working

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, clock

I have been using [Gnome Clock Override Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/) for a couple of months and everything was working well until recently. Now, all I am able to see on the clock bar is the markup language I use to create my customised line.

Simple example, instead of seeing:

> 17.30

I see:

> %H.%M

The latter being one of the examples in the markup used by the extension.

Of course, if I disable the extension I can see the basic clock but not all the rest.  I am using other extensions and I have tried disabling them all to see if this 'fixes' the issue but no change.

Currently running Ubuntu 18.04.1 with Gnome 3.28.2.

Comment: It seems to be a bug ([recent user reviews here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/) support that). Please report this issue to the developer of the extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After submitting the bug report, I got the following reply from one of the developers:

> This issue has been fixed and pushed to GNOME Extensions. It’s pending a manual review (these reviews are done by volunteers and they can take forever) but the update should be available soon.
>
> If you’re impatient, you can find and apply the patch on GitHub:
> https://github.com/stuartlangridge/gnome-shell-clock-override/issues/13

So, it is now only a matter of time for us to get a fix.

**UPDATE** : Release has now been reviewed and available for download.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version is pending review, until you can use that:

```
%H:%M    %;@
```

"%; @" generates a number, I do not know what this number is but it works